# How to populate dropdownmenuitem from another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make 2 dropdownbutton. 1st one will list all the states. Then when they change that value, the 2nd one will populate with the cities in that state. Any help is appreciated.

I'm get this error:

**The following _CastError was thrown during paint(): Null check operator used on a null value**

My Form:

```
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Origin - State",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _originState = value as String?;
                    });
                  },
                  items: cityMap.map((val) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: val["state"], child: Text(val["state"]));
                  }).toList(),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Origin - City",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _originCity = value;
                    });
                  },
                  items: cityMap.where((element) {
                    return element["state"] == _originState;
                  }).map<List<String>>((e) {
                    return e["city"];
                  }).map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((val) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: val.toString(),
                      child: Text(val.toString()),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

My cityMap:

```
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> cityMap = [
    {
      "state": "California",
      "city": [
        "Sacramento",
        "San Francisco",
        "San Jose",
      ],
    },
    {
      "state": "Nevada",
      "city": [
        "Carson City",
        "Las Vegas",
        "Reno",
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all we make a method for the country

```
String _selectedCountry="India";
var country=. 
{'India':'IN','Pakistan':'PAK','Nepal':'NP','Bangladesh':'BD'};

List _countries=[];
CountryDependentDropDown(){
  country.forEach((key, value) {
    _countries.add(key);
  });}
```

Here I have set the default to a country in a variable(_selectedCountry), And in the _countries I just put new map

Now we can show it in drop down

```
Container(
          width: 400,
          child: DropdownButton(
            value: _selectedCountry,
            onChanged: (newValue){
              setState(() {
                _selectedCountry="$newValue";
              });

            },
            items:_countries.map((country){
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text(country),
                value:country,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

You will find in the above method that when the user changes the country, the setState method will replace the default value to selected value .

And we will send the state[ StateDependentDropDown() ] method to the country changed by the user. Like this :

```
Container(
         width: 400,
         child: DropdownButton(
           value: _selectedCountry,
           onChanged: (newValue){
             setState(() {
                 StateDependentDropDown(country[newValue]);
               _selectedCountry="$newValue";
             });

           },
           items:_countries.map((country){
             return DropdownMenuItem(
               child: new Text(country),
               value:country,
             );
           }).toList(),
         ),
       ),
```

and the StateDependentDropDown method is Like this :

```
String _selectedState="";
var state=.
```

{'Jharkhand':'IN','Panjab':'IN','Baluchistan':'PAK','Dhaka':'BD','Janakpur':'NP'};

```
List _states=[];
StateDependentDropDown(countryShortName){
  state.forEach((key, value) {
    if(countryShortName==value){
      _states.add(key);
    }
  });
  _selectedState= _states[0];
}
```

Now here you can see that in a loop I have added a condition that the country the user has selected, only the state of that county will be added to the Map object containing the _states.

```
if(countryShortName==value){
     _states.add(key);
   }
```

So now after filtering the country’s accounting states, you can display them in the drop down.

```
Container(
         width: 400,
         child: DropdownButton(
           value: _selectedState,
           onChanged: (newValue){
             print(newValue);
             setState(() {
               print(newValue);
               _cities=[];
               CityDependentDropDown(newValue);

              _selectedState="$newValue";
             });

           },
           items:_states.map((state){
             return DropdownMenuItem(
               child: new Text(state),
               value:state,
             );
           }).toList(),
         ),
       ),
```

And then the same process will be done for the filter of cities

if this help please mark it as answer

Comment: Thank you! Let me give a try and let you.